# change default /webservices path for Apache CXF SOAP service

Tags: soap, cxf, jax-ws, apache-tomee

I'm using tomEE 1.7.1 with Apache CXF 2.6.14 inside.

I have a component that serves a WSDL first web service:

```
        @Stateless
        @WebService(
                endpointInterface   = "com.mycompany.SecurityTokenServiceWS", 
                targetNamespace     = "http://sts.mycompany/wsdl/", 
                serviceName         = "SecurityTokenService", 
                portName            = "TokenService")
        @SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL) 
        public class TokenService implements SecurityTokenServiceWS {

        //service methods
    }
```

When I deploy the web app, I see this log:

```
Jan 30, 2015 12:47:22 PM org.apache.openejb.server.webservices.WsService deployApp
INFORMATION: Webservice(wsdl=http://localhost:8080//webservices/TokenService, qname={http://sts.mycompany.com/wsdl/}SecurityTokenService) --> Ejb(id=TokenService)
```

In result the web service is available on: http://localhost:8080/webservices/TokenService.

What I like to have is that the service runs directly on: http://localhost:8080/TokenService.

I have no idea where the "webservices" path element comes from. It isn't in the WSDL and not in any configuration file. My web application runs directly under the context path / (ROOT).

Is there a magic CXF servlet that is bonded to /webservices? How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this comes from TomEE which uses subcontext webservices by default.

This sample shows how to change it https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=tomee.git;a=tree;f=examples/change-jaxws-url;h=2f88382bd4f925ec27c7305e74d361c8baf46a92;hb=ebe63371a22709a50e79c42206b5e9a0fd8946cc (the interesting file is https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=tomee.git;a=blob;f=examples/change-jaxws-url/src/main/resources/META-INF/openejb-jar.xml;h=6c0ba44b14eb2e67a550c65d890d325c8bf409b7;hb=ebe63371a22709a50e79c42206b5e9a0fd8946cc)

Note: if you just want to rename /webservices you can set in conf/system.properties tomee.jaxws.subcontext=/myothersubcontext

PS: if you go with openejb-jar.xml solution note there is the equivalent for openejb-jar.xml 1.1 which is just the property openejb.webservice.deployment.address in your ejb-deployment properties

Comment: conf/system.properties solved the problem. I configured tomee.jaxws.subcontext = /. openejb-jar.xml and openejb.webservice.deployment.address does not work. This setting seams to change the name of the endpoint but not the sub context. If I configure openejb.webservice.deployment.address = /, I get the service under http://localhost:8080//webservices/. A solution without passing system properties would be nicer :( but ok it works now. Thanks!

Comment: right, there are 2 configs: 1) subcontext, 2) name of the webservice. With the 2 mentionned configs you have a full control over the deployment. True tomee.jaxws.subcontext one is global but it is generally defined for the whole container. That said if you think we need to support it in application.properties as well it is doable.

Answer (score 0):

To change the publishiing address you need to change endpoint configuration. For now I guess you have no configuration and all is default. You need to create file **service.xml** (any name) and provide path to it either using **web.xml** CXFServlet init-parameter "**config-location**" or using **Spring**.

Here is the file contents http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html

And here is an example how to do it with spring http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html